# Need to center image in web page via CSS

Tags: css, image, center

I'd like to center an image in a page both vertically and horizontally even when the browser is resized.

Currently, I use this CSS:

```
.centeredImage {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: -150px;
}
```

And this HTML:

```
<img class="centeredImage" src="images/logo.png">
```

It centers in FF but not IE (image center is placed at upper left corner).  Any ideas?

-Robot

Comment: Do you "know" the image height?

Comment: Yes, although obviously the extra credit question is how to do this generically for any image.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using this :

```
position: absolute
```

Comment: That did the trick... now on to trying to get it to work for any image dynamically adjusting for the image's width and height.

Comment: jquery will help you with that.

Comment: @Tesserex
Since when is jQuery considered CSS?

Answer (score 20):

I solved it this way:

```
img.class-name{

    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    left: 0; 
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;  
}
```

Comment: Works in current releases of Opera, Chrome, Firefox and Safari. IE anyone?

Answer (score 3):

the universal KISS ("keep it simple and stupid") way:

```
<p style="text-align: center;"> <img src="myImage.png" /></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a tricky way, but it works:

CSS:

```
html, body, #wrapper {
   height:100%;
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   border: 0;
}
#wrapper td {
   vertical-align: middle;
   text-align: center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
   <table id="wrapper">
      <tr>
         <td><img src="my_cool_image.png" alt="hello world" /></td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
text-align:center;

vertical-align:middle;
```

[vertical-align](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp)

Should to the trick

Comment: note that text-align needs to be applied to the container, not the image. Also vertical-align doesn't work for me, testing with IE7.

Answer (score 0):

If the supplied answers do not work and/or not consistent in each browser you may want to give this a shot:

http://andreaslagerkvist.com/jquery/center/

```
text-align:center;
```

Should get it, though.

Comment: That jQuery plugin looks fantastic, although I'm using ExtJS, so I have to see if i can translate it.

Comment: Ahh, maybe an equivalent plugin exists. Not familiar with ExtJS.

Answer (score 0):

IE has issues with `position: fixed` (along with a million other things), so I would advise against that if compatibility is important.

Use `position: absolute` if the container doesn't have to scroll. Otherwise you'll need some js to adjust the top and left of your image as you do scroll.

`text-align: center` should work if applied to the image's container, but not to the image itself. But of course that only addresses the horizontal, not vertical. `vertical-align: middle` doesn't work for me, even with a large enough container.

Auto margins don't work in IE, at least when I test it.

Answer (score 0):

clear: both;
margin: auto;

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
 .centeredImage {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      margin-top: image-height/2;
      margin-left: image-width/2;
    }
```

since you mentioned:

```
 margin-top: -50px;
 margin-left: -150px;
```

And if its aligning properly to the center then your image height would be 50x2=100px; & width 150x2=300px;

Answer (score 0):

```
.image {
    position: fixed;
    margin: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it! This method is rock solid and works on all major browsers.

```
style="position: fixed; margin: 0 50%; left: -850px; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0;"
```

I have simply used a left of half the width of the image and then shunted it across using margin. Works a treat :)

Comment: Have you tried this at different window widths - ie responsive?

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple, cross browser, auto resize method. Taking an image with width of 200px. Take half the width then do the following:

```
   #imgcent1 {
   left: calc (100% - 100px  /  2 );
   /*rest of code*/
   }
```

Make sure there is "white space" to avoid negative and positive numbers (best using this convention for all operands). It will auto resize. Just try it and hopefully, testing on other browsers will ensure that it becomes the standard as intended.

Answer (score 0):

A single image on the web & responsive

**Background Image:**

/image.png

**CSS:**

```
html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; }

.bg-image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(image.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: contain;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <div class="bg-image">Some text not displayed</div>
</body>
```