# Teach Me To Center an Image with CSS

Tags: html, css

I've searched up this issue and found nothing that works... In a previous post it was suggested that I didn't use center. I looked it up and now see why it is at a disadvantage to use it... So... I tried with the whole CSS side of life and nothing has worked. I'm using HTML Kit-Tools, so not sure if it's a program issue, most likely my useless intellect...

Therefore, I present my very basic page code, please teach me how to do this with CSS and explain why to me. Thanks in advance,

Pete

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Access All Areas - Live</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
<div style="min-width: 960px; min-height: 390px; margin: 0 auto;">
<!-- AAA Logo -->
<div class="image">
    <center>
    <img src="a1.jpg" alt="Access All Areas Logo" width="750px" height="320px">
    </center>
</div>
<!--Navigation Bar-->
<div class="nav">
    <center>
    <ul>
    <li class="main"><a href="main.html">HOME</a></li>
    <strong><li class="live"><a href="live.html">LIVE</a></li></strong>
    <li class="studio"><a href="studio.html">STUDIO</a></li>
    <li class="fashion"><a href="fashion.html">FASHION</a></li>
    <li class="weddings"><a href="weddings.html">WEDDINGS</a></li>
    <li class="portraits"><a href="portraits.html">PORTRAITS</a></li>
    <li class="about"><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
    <a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
    </center>
</div><!--Nav-->
</div><!--Style-->
<!--COVER IMAGE-->
<center>
<div class="cover">
<img src="images/live.jpg" alt="Access All Areas Live Image" width="1140px" height="740px">
</center>   
</div><!--Cover-->
<!--Copyright-->
<p><strong>ALL RIGHTS RESERVED ACCESS ALL AREAS PHOTOGRAPHY</p></strong>
</body>
</html>
```

And the dreaded CSS

```
li {
display:inline;
}

.nav a {
font-family:arial;
font-size:14px;
color: black;
padding:0px 70px 0px 20px;
}

a {
text-decoration:none;
}

.main {
text-weight:strong;
}

p {
font-family:arial;
font-size:10px;
font-weight:bold;
text-align:left;
padding-left:372px;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need to center image in web page via CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502206/need-to-center-image-in-web-page-via-css)

Comment: does it req a /img after or is it self closing?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp

Comment: Quick fix: https://jsfiddle.net/coxfhfjs/

Comment: Neither of those worked.... The first aligns it right, the second sends it slightly left, and if I click on another tab and then come back to it, it too aligns left

Comment: you have two common ways to do it : text-align on parent or reset display and margin to image itself : https://jsfiddle.net/coxfhfjs/1/

Comment: GCyrillus, I award thee, Kudos.... Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a simple css class for your images in your css file such as -

```
.centerit { display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right:auto; }
```

Include the class name in the image such as your one -

```
<img class="centerit" src="a1.jpg" alt="Access All Areas Logo" width="750px" height="320px">
```

This makes the image into a display block and the margin left and right auto will center the image within the `<div class="image">` that you are using. The image will center within your div, your div is the full page width.  If your DIV was smaller it would center it within the DIV width. This way you can remove the old `<center>` tags.
For your text within the `<DIV class="nav">` you can just use `.nav { text-align: center; }` , this will center the text.

Answer (score 0):

I always `margin:0 auto` and it works. Give the image some width. That's all. ie `#myimg {width:700px; margin:0 auto; position:relative;}`